# C# WPF Control whose name I cannot find

Tags: c#, wpf, border

I'm trying to make a few fields and put them inside some "Border".
However, I'm searching for something like the "Pet" border example in this picture:

[image: Border Example]

Answer (score 1):

It's called a GroupBox.

Here's a good example on how to use it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Pizza" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="236" Width="263">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="253" Margin="0,0,-2,-12">
        <Label Content="These are some pizza toppings."
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Cheese" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="10,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Mushrooms" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="10,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Olives" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="10,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Taken from: http://www.dotnetperls.com/groupbox-wpf

Answer (score 0):

This is what you search: [GroupBox](http://www.dotnetperls.com/groupbox-wpf)